# Cohomology: Crossed Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

**Problem**

Given abelian groups $A,B$ and $C$.

> Are $\mathrm{Hom}(A \otimes B,C)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(A,C)\otimes\mathrm{Hom}(B,C)$ isomorphic?

Can the tensor hom adjunction help here?

**Motivation**

Given chain complexes $C_*$ and $D_*$
as well as an abelian group $A$.

Consider their cochain complexes $C^*A$ and $D^*A$
with coefficients in $A$; see definition below.

> There are crossed products:
>   $$\times:C^pA\times D^qA\to(C_*\otimes D_*)^{p+q}A$$
>   $$\times:C^pA\times D^qA\to(C^*A\otimes D^*A)^{p+q}$$
>   Do these products agree?

They seem to look the same?

**Definition**

Cochain complex:
$$C^rA:=\mathrm{Hom}(C_r,A)$$
Tensor chain complex:
$$(C_*\otimes D_*)_r:=\bigoplus_{p+q=r}C_p\otimes D_q$$
Analogously for cochains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z^n\otimes\mathbb Z^m,\mathbb Z^p)\cong\mathbb Z^{nmp}$$
but
$$\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z^n,\mathbb Z^p)\otimes\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z^m,\mathbb Z^p)\cong\mathbb Z^{nmp^2}$$